# Imprimir mediante Microsoft Print to PDF

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

estoy intentando imprimir usuando Microsoft Print to PDF pero cuando abro el documento generado esta en blanco.

```
 try
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Total\EX-2017-005632.pdf");
            info.Verb = "Print";
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "Microsoft Print to PDF";
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrintToFile = true;
            pd.PrinterSettings.PrintFileName = Path.Combine(@"C:\Total\", "DocumentoNuevo" + ".pdf");
            pd.Print();
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;

        }
```

Comment: ahí donde le indicas lo que es el contenido del pdf???

Comment: Me podrias indicar que es lo que me estaria faltando.

Comment: Es que no veo donde le indicas lo que le pasas para rellenar el pdf, un string, enteros, algún objeto, otro pdf...

Comment: mirate esto: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Print-PDF-file-in-C-5b6e66b7

Comment: intento pasarle otro pdf

Comment: Si lo que estás intentando imprimir es un control de usuario, si este utiliza una imagen de fondo, la impresora de PDF de Microsoft genera un pdf en blanco. Por probar, prueba a imprmiir en XPS, si el documento es el esperado, el problema es en la impresora de PDF de Microsoft, por lo que tendrás que utilizar otra impresora de PDF.

Comment: La dificultad que presenta es que imprime y envía y no se sabe a donde